# stochastic calculus - brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic

I don't know how to prove this :

let be $X_t = \int_{0}^{t}\sigma_{u}dW_{u}$ where $\sigma_{t}$ is a predictable process.

If $|\sigma_{t}| = c$ a.s. how can I prove that $X_{t}=c*\beta_{t}$ (equality in distribution) ? (obvious if there wouldn't be absolute value..)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $X$ is a continuous martingale. Moreover, the quadratic variation is given by
\begin{align*}
\langle X_t, \, X_t\rangle = \int_0^t |\sigma_u|^2 du = c^2 t.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
\langle X_t/c, \, X_t/c\rangle = t.
\end{align*}
From Levy's characterization, $X/c$ is by law a Brownian motion, which we denote by $\beta$. Then, by law,
\begin{align*}
X_t = c\, \beta_t.
\end{align*}

Comment: TY ! I wouldn't have thought at Levy's characterization...